# Herokuで自分のアプリのホスト名を取得したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

HerokuでRailsでReview.appを利用しています。（PR毎に環境ができるやつ）

メールの設定で下記のようにホスト名を設定する必要があるのですが、今のアプリの名前等、ホスト名を知る方法はありますでしょうか？

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
end
```

環境変数からは取れないようなので・・・。

Comment: やったことはないですが、request.host の値を Thread.current に放り込んで、それをMailer内で取得するとか？参考 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497006/how-to-discover-the-external-hostname-from-within-a-heroku-cedar-application

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。app.jsonに下記で環境変数から取れるようになりました。

```
{
  "name":"foo",
  "scripts":{
    "postdeploy": "rake db:setup"
  },
  "env":{
    "HEROKU_APP_NAME": { "required": true },
  }
}
```